# swift xcode 8.0 - uiimageview drag inside uiview

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimageview, drag

I have two UIimageview images which are draggable using touchesBegan and touchesMoved however they can be dragged anywhere on the screen without any limitations. I am trying to limit the UIimageview to be only draggable inside the UIimage (certain area).

Any idea what is the best approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `CGRectContainsPoint` to limit the area.

For example:

```
let point = touch.location(in: self) // or elsewhere
if CGRectContainsPoint(image.frame, point) {
  // could drag
} else {
  // stop dragging 
}
```

Comment: what you mean "touch.location"